# How to remove previous price of products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

I am using magento 1.9 , i want to know how to remove the previous strikethrough  price of products as shown here https://prnt.sc/orfv5b

Comment: You can just remove special price from price tab in product from admin clear cache and re-index it should remove strike through price

Comment: @AmanAlam i cant find this option

Comment: @Nafisa Do you want to remove special price?

Comment: @MonarkBhawani . How can i add a boolen field over here so that the admin can select whether to select strikethrough price or not. prnt.sc/org7l2.  I want to add a checkbox that can be selected or deselected to show strikethrough price

Answer (score 0):

The strikethrough price is the product price and the other price shown on the page is the discounted price.

If you don't want to show the strikethrough price, then:

- Copy the special price
- Put it into the price field
- Remove the value from the special price field
- Save the product

Screenshots attached for reference:

- https://nimb.ws/q8Q0Gs
- https://nimb.ws/t2aZ1Y

Comment: There is not only one product. There are multiple products

Comment: Then, you have to set prices and remove special prices by a custom PHP script.

Comment: kumar . How can i add a boolen field over here so that the admin can select whether to select strikethrough price or not. https://prnt.sc/org7l2. I want to add a checkbox that can be selected or deselected to show strikethrough price